# Saving in one repository and making the others reflect the save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity in my Spring project which are ApplicationUser and Tournament

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Length(min = 2, max = 60)
    private String password;

    private Long tsRegistration;

    private Long tslLastLogin;

    private Long bonusCredit;

    private String nationality;

    private String battleTag;

    private String mmr;

    private boolean enabled;

    private boolean tokenExpired;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicationUser")
    private List<ConfirmationUri> confirmationUri;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_matches",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "matches_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Matches> matches;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    }




@Entity
public class Tournament {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    public String name;

    public Integer maxPlayers;

    public String game;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="listOfUsers")
    public List<Long> ids;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament")
    public List<Matches> matches;

    public String imagePath;

    public Long timestamp;

    public TournamentState tournamentState;

    public String region;

    public String type;
    }
```

I implemented a REST controller that lets a user register to a given tournament

```
   @RequestMapping(method = POST, path = "/tournaments/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> registerInTournament(@PathVariable long id) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    List<ApplicationUser> userList = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName());

    if (userList.isEmpty())
        return ResponseRestBuilder.createErrorResponse("User with email " + auth.getName() + " not found");

    ApplicationUser user = userList.get(0);

    List<Tournament> tournamentList = tournamentRepository.findById(id);

    if (tournamentList.isEmpty())
        return ResponseRestBuilder.createErrorResponse("Tournament id " + id+ " not found");

    Tournament tournament = tournamentList.get(0);

    ApplicationUser user1 = userList.get(0);

    if (tournament.getUsers().contains(user))
        return ResponseRestBuilder.createErrorResponse("User id " + user.id + " is already registered in tournament" +
                "with id " + id);

    if(tournament.getUsers().size() >= tournament.maxPlayers)
        return ResponseRestBuilder.createErrorResponse("Tournament has reached max capacity");

    tournament.addUsers(user1);

    tournamentRepository.save(tournament);

    user1.tournament.add(tournament);

    applicationUserRepository.save(user1);

    return ResponseRestBuilder.createSuccessResponse("user successfully registered to tournament");
}
```

In order to be able to store the information that a user is registered to a tournament, I not only need to perform the tournament save

```
tournament.addUsers(user1);

tournamentRepository.save(tournament);
```

but also the application user save

```
user1.tournament.add(tournament);

applicationUserRepository.save(user1);
```

Is this the correct behavior? Is there a way to just save one repository and have the changes reflected in the others?

Comment: I see this problem more from design issue, why you want to save tournament information in user. If you want to check, which tournament user x is playing, you can always query tournament DB, anyway if you still need two way binding between tournament and user, you need to save/update both entity, one suggestion is to do it one transaction.

Comment: What you are looking for is Cascading: https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading